# How to use command stdin in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I've tried [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/command_module.html):

```
- name: Log into Docker registry
  command: docker login --username "{{ docker_registry_username }}" --password-stdin
  stdin: "{{ docker_registry_password }}"
```

This results in a warning and a failing command:

> [WARNING]: Ignoring invalid attribute: stdin

…

> Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

I've also tried [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/27335#issuecomment-322643039):

```
- name: Log into Docker registry
  command: docker login --username "{{ docker_registry_username }}" --password-stdin
    stdin: "{{ docker_registry_password }}"
```

This results in a syntax error:

> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.

Does `command` `stdin` actually work in Ansible 2.7? If so, how am I supposed to use it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to use the `stdin` argument to the `command` module, take a look at [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/command_module.html), which show examples using other options such as `creates`, which looks like this:

```
# You can also use the 'args' form to provide the options.
- name: This command will change the working directory to somedir/ and will only run when /path/to/database doesn't exist.
  command: /usr/bin/make_database.sh arg1 arg2
  args:
    chdir: somedir/
    creates: /path/to/database
```

For your use case, you would want:

```
- name: Log into Docker registry
  command: docker login --username "{{ docker_registry_username }}" --password-stdin
  args:
    stdin: "{{ docker_registry_password }}"
```

Your first attempt failed because you were setting `stdin` as a key at the task level (like `when` or `ignore_errors`, etc), when you actually want it to be an argument to the `command` module.

Your second attempt failed because it wasn't valid YAML.

Comment: What if the command gets stuck while `docker login` ? Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use command/shell to log into Docker registry?
Ansible has docker_login module for that:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_login_module.html
it's in preview, from community, but it works.

You can create vault file with sensitive data.

Comment: This won't work because `reset_connection` doesn't work with `ansible_local`.

Comment: if you are talking about ansible_connection=local for localhost...hm...yes, it could be true. You could add ssh key to localhost and change connection to ssh :)

Comment: No, I mean using the Vagrant `ansible_local` directive/plugin/something.

Answer (score -6):

Sounds like you want to use the Ansible expect module.  See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I really don't. I'm asking why documented functionality doesn't seem to work at all. Expect is a horrible hack.